# What is meant by "JavaScript APIs"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

My understanding of APIs is limited to the kind where I send ajax calls to a certain URL, and do something with the data I get back. For example, I can use the data from the Rotten Tomatoes API to search and manipulate data from Rotten Tomatoes, such as movie reviews and metadata for a given movie.

What I'm confused about is how *that* is an API at the same that jQuery is also considered an API (as are dozens of other "JavaScript APIs"). I don't seem to be sending requests back and forth to be able to use jQuery, for example, since I can include the `.js` file in my local file structure. Does it have to do with the built-in methods it provides me?

*If so, what is the difference between a library and an API?*

This is the Wikipedia definition:

> An application programming interface (API) specifies how some software components should interact with each other. In addition to accessing databases or computer hardware, such as hard disk drives or video cards, an API can be used to ease the work of programming graphical user interface components.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface

What does that mean in the context of JavaScript? And what does it mean in terms of how I use it? Can anyone take a moment and explain this in practical (non-abstract) layman's terms?

Comment: jquery is a library, and it ***has*** an api. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface the term `api` is often misused.

Comment: so, in what sense does it have an API? How does a person use it? What is it used for?

Comment: The api is specified here: http://api.jquery.com an api is nothing more than a specification of how you are to interact with an application, or in this case, the library.

Comment: *"...in practical (non-abstract) layman's terms"* But it is abstract. An API is just the programming interface provided to developers. It isn't representative of any specific technology.

Comment: It's like really `Application programming interface` nothing more. Say you make a library, weather it's js or ruby or no matter what, you provide an API for your future users. Look at example. Rails, a Ruby framework for web applications: http://api.rubyonrails.org/ You can go there and look at all the specific things you can do with Rails [without modifying its source code]

Comment: so how, in this context, does the term "API" differ from "Documentation"?

Comment: It doesn't in this case, the two are one and the same. However, there is documentation for jquery that isn't part of the api, for example, http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: API is the interface. Documentation is the explanation of how it works. The documentation provides (or should provide) certain guarantees of behavior.

Comment: INTERESTING. That explains so much. Thank you. So, can you think of a time when API and Documentation would not be synonymous?

Comment: Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs VS Laravel API: http://laravel.com/api/4.1/

Comment: Docs ≈ Guide, API ≈ Specs

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com vs http://api.jquery.com or http://jqueryui.com vs http://api.jqueryui.com

Comment: simply put, JS sees everything as an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An API is simply a **published contract**.

It defines the **operations** available, and their respective **inputs** and **outputs** if they exist.

It doesn't matter if you are calling a web service, a JavaScript function, or consuming a binary. They all have some formal published contract through which you interact.

So while a Web Service has a very strict contract because *only* the public methods are exposed, jQuery defines a set of methods that are *intended* for external public consumption.

Example:

```
var MyObject = function(){
   var _state = "I'm private";

   //Not intended for public consumption
   this._prefix = "Hello, my name is ";

   //Part of formal API
   this.name = "Johnson";
};

// Part of formal API
MyObject.prototype.sayHello = function(){
   console.log(this._prefix + this.name);
};

var obj = new MyObject();
obj.name = "Josh";
obj.sayHello(); // "Hello, my name is Josh"
```

In the above example the object has a public API that is intended for use, but it also has some members you can manipulate, but aren't intended to. There might be any number of reasons to have things like this in your object, but messing with them might have unintended consequences.

**The author is free to move, rename and change the implementation details so long as he maintains the external public contract (API).**

Again, an **API is a documented contract**... nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

In laymen's terms, API is much like an added feature to anything that you need to configure to work with your own product. In context of jQuery, it provides you added functionality over native javascript. You can configure your elements to work in conjunction with this functionality to provide you extra features with lesser amount of code and effort.
However a library is just a collection of some methods that can be used again and again in your software components to avoid code redundancy.
However, in terms of working in real world, they both may look like same.